# How to update a List with new Objects in a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a telegram bot with Python that sends a new word every day. I already have the schedule function setup. As for the words - I created a class terms and I'm using the pop() method to choose the last word from the list of objects in the class. However, I still haven't been able to automatically update the object list when I add a new term to the object class.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def dailyword():
class terms:
    def __init__(self, word, meaning, example):
        self.word = word
        self.meaning = meaning
        self.example = example

Munchkin = terms("Munchkin", 'a word of endearment used by parents with their children','Munchkin, eat your vegetables to grow strong')
Babe = terms("Babe",'a word of endearment that couples use','Babe, do you want to go surfing this weekend?')
Sweetie = terms("Sweetie", 'a word used between couples to show affection',"Sweetie, can you take out the trash?")

objectList = [Munchkin, Babe, Sweetie]
for x in objectList:
    popObject = (objectList.pop()) 

newdict = {'word':popObject.word,'meaning':popObject.meaning,'example':popObject.example}

wordoftheday = "BuzzWord of the day is -{word}\nMeaning -{meaning}\nExample -{example}".format(**newdict)

telegram_bot_sendtext(wordoftheday)
```

Comment: Can you be clear with code what is not working for you?

Comment: Hi! Thank for your answer. So when I run the program the message is sent to my telegram group as planned. But the program sends the same word everytime. I don't know how to:

1. Make it so that the objectList updates if I were to add an object to the Class terms.
2. Make it so that during the next iteration, when the scheduler fires up the function, for it to pop() the next object from the list. It doesn't seem to update. 

Appreciate your enlightment.

Comment: I've thought about using a loop 

**while (len(objectList) > 0
objectList = ['Muchkin', 'Babe', 'Sweetie']
popObject = (objectList.pop())
print(popObject)**

But I'm getting syntax error on the condition.

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. The line `objectList.append(new_word)` in the `add_word` function does exactly that - *automatically update the object list when I add a new term to the object class*

Comment: Thank @Tomerikoo actually. @ lllrnr101 helped me with that function. So I got rid of the Loop. Above is the updated code. However, now I'm getting the following error on the `send_word` function - ** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pop' **

Comment: @danielcorrea you shouldn't edit the question in a way that changes it's meaning and invalidates other's answers. If you have questions following an answer given to you, either clarify them in comments on that answer or ask a new question. You should keep each question with its original intent and respect the effort people put into answering you. I have reverted your edits, please don't change your question

Comment: Based on comments, I think the initial question has been answered. So I will not be responding on this question any more. 

Daniel, please see suggestion in my answer's comments to make it work. 

@Tomerikoo he updated the question on my request because I wanted to see his latest code with my revisions in it. I did not know that updating is kind of frowned upon or not generally advised. Thanks for revert and sorry about the confusion created.

This question can be closed based on OP's feedback now.

Comment: @lllrnr101 it is ok to update the question with more information, but the problem is that once the OP updated with the new code he was using from your answer, it makes your answer seem irrelevant. As if ***you*** just copy-pasted the code from the question... You see the problem? As I said, edits are perfectly fine for adding information and clarifications, but not to change the question entirely. As we are asking about code here - then changing the code drastically changes the question...

Comment: @danielcorrea As I already asked you, please don't change the question and invalidate others' answers. You can accept the answer and ask a new follow-up question. You can provide a link to this question for context

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for the heads up. I'm still getting the hang of how threads work here. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. And thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: With pleasure. Please keep in mind that this site is not a common *forum*-like website for interactive conversations. It is a Q & A which means questions with their answers. Once you change your question according to an answer, this answer becomes irrelevant and future readers will get confused. The answers you get are not only for you - they are to serve anyone arriving here with a similar problem. To avoid that in the future, make sure to (re)take the [tour] and read about [ask]. You can also go over the [help] and read around on [meta]

Answer (score 0):

The program sends the same word every time because you iterate on list and keep popping items which means the final `popObject` is always `objectList[0]`

You do not need to loop on the list. Just use `objectList.pop()` once.

Something like below:

```
def add_word(word, meaning, example):
    new_word = terms(word, meaning, example)
    objectList.append(new_word)


def send_word(objectList):
    popObject = objectList.pop()
    newdict = {'word':popObject.word,'meaning':popObject.meaning,'example':popObject.example}

    wordoftheday = "BuzzWord of the day is -{word}\nMeaning -{meaning}\nExample -{example}".format(**newdict)

    telegram_bot_sendtext(wordoftheday)
```

Hope you are enlightened!

Comment: Thank you! Though I understood why the same word is repeating, it's not because I end up popping all the words out, but because the schedule module is not being applied to all of the functions. So the send function only sends the item it popped when I initially run the program. Also, I tried adding your functions but I'm getting the following error - **send_word() missing 1 required positional argument: 'objectList'** function.

Comment: Update your question with your current code.

Comment: I think you need to call `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(send_word, objectList)`

And also modify addWord to `add_word(word, meaning, example, objectList)`
`

Comment: I keep getting this error with the updated code. AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: Please update the code. I ran this code and it worked fine.

Comment: The OP has since modified the question after initial suggestion.

Comment: Ohh now I see that the code in the question is your answer... Sorry for that, will rollback the question

Comment: @lllrnr101  I've ran the updated code (please see initial question) and it get the following errors - 
`add_word() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'word', 'meaning', 'example', and 'objectList'`
`send_word() missing 1 required positional argument: 'objectList'`